# Symfony 2.8 FOSUserBundle Change the redirection after the password resetting

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm following the [FOSUserbundle Official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) in order to change the redirection after a password resetting procedure. I created a new class named PasswordResettingListener and add it to services.yml

The class is executes up to the getSubscribedEvents() method but Symfony never calls my specific method that performs the redirect. Am I misunderstanding something?

src/AppBundle/EventListener/PasswordResettingListener.php:

```
<?php 
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/PasswordResettingListener.php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class PasswordResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router){
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
    * CALLED!
    */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
        FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
        die("alone"); //never called 
        $url = $this->router->generate('tarifs'); //nevercalled
        die("die alone !!!!!"); // never called 
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url)); // ""
    }
}
```

The service is recorded here (/app/config/services.yml):
    # app/config/services.yml
    services:

```
app.form.registration:
    class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }

app.password_resetting:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\PasswordResettingListener
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score 1):

src/AppBundle/EventListener/PasswordResettingListener.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
    use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

    class PasswordResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        private $router;
        private $security;

        public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, AuthorizationChecker $security) {
            $this->router = $router;
            $this->security = $security;
        }

        public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
            return [
                FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
            ];
        }


        public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
            $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
        }

    }
```

and app/config/services.yml services:

```
  acme_user.password_resetting:
          class: src/AppBundle/EventListener/PasswordResettingListener
          arguments: [ "@router", "@security.authorization_checker" ]
          tags:
              - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOSUser's routing in order to change the redirect.
When importing it's routes, you have two options: either you add all by adding

`fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"`

or each of them, by path. This is the one for the user's profile:

```
fos_user_profile:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
prefix: /profile
```

Just change it's prefix by your desired path and that's all.

PS: I tried to use Event Listener as well but it didn't worked.

Good luck!